# What is the surface area of Falcon 9 payload fairing?

Tags: spacex, fairings

what is the external surface area of the payload fairing of the Falcon 9 ?

Comment: How exact do you need it? The users guide gives the fairing dimensions, it should be easy to calculate an approximate area. Page 30 https://www.spaceflightnow.com/falcon9/001/f9guide.pdf

Comment: I'm kinda using it already for approximating a surface area. Needed to verify. I break  it into ogive/cylinder/cone for simplification.  Although I'd appreciate some actual values(research papers etc)

Comment: Was looking at someone providing values from a CAD model or as such